# How do you lower an sql value with php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Basic translation  English Dutch:

- Aantal = Amount
- ArtikelNr= Article Number
- VOORRAAD = storage
- BestellingNr = Order Number
- Prijs = price

So I'm currently working on a webshop and I find myself with the next problem. How to lower a value in my database with php?

The checkout is as the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BESTELREGEL (Best_BestellingNr, Art_ArtikelNr, Prijs, Aantal) VALUES
    (".$bestelnr.", ".$product[0].", ".$product[1].", 0.0)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn)."<br>in file ".__FILE__." on line ".__LINE__);
```

(sorry for the Dutch therms. The checkout inserts data into the order table.)

After I've done that I now want to lower the amount that is in the storage table.

I tried it with the following code:

```
$aantalcheck = $row['Aantal'];
$artnrcheck = $row['ArtikelNr'];

$query="UPDATE VOORRAAD SET `Aantal`=(`Aantal`-'$aantalcheck') WHERE `VOORRAAD`.`Art_ArtikelNr` = '$artnrcheck'";
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something small wrong here because if I insert the statement into SQL with say Aantal = 2 and ArtikelNr = 2. It updates the ammount.

Am I requesting the variables wrong? Or executing the query wrong?

I'm kinda stuck here so I hoped one of you could help!

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you checking the UPDATE query for errors? Have you looked into your error logs?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($query)` to see what your generated query looks like? checked for errors after executing the query? just defining `$query` doesn't DO anything, you still need to feed it to `mysqli_query(...)`

Comment: If I do a vardump I get string(80) "UPDATE VOORRAAD SET `Aantal`=(`Aantal`-'') WHERE `VOORRAAD`.`Art_ArtikelNr` = ''". So it's not putting the variables in the querry

Comment: We don't see anything here that populates `$row`. Are you executing a query (SELECT statement) and fetching the rows? Assigning a string to a variable named `$query` doesn't execute the `UPDATE`. (As far as something you're doing wrong, those dynamically generated SQL statement should be **static** SQL text with **bind placeholders**. Prepared statements are really *not that hard*.)

Comment: For some reason I thought $row was the way to get the values Idk why. I now changed them into $product[0] and $product[1](corresponding to the rightfull variable) Thank you I didn't notice.

Comment: Can you please correct your tags in your questions? Is that MySQL or SQL-Server question?

Comment: It was mysql. All fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I suppose you have more code in between that you are not showing.
Such as selecting data first, fetching the $row from the $results, actually executing the update-query, and so on.

You've just got a typo:
it should be

```
$artnrcheck = $row['Art_ArtikelNr'];
```

But think about prepared statements as spencer suggested!

Comment: Also that and also I should have uses the $product[0] and $product[1] not the insert Art_ArtikelNr and Aantal because that doesn't mean annything